# Returning into variable from function called in tkinter.Button command

Tags: python, tkinter

In the code below, which I made more simple for this purpose, I first create a function and then make a button, which is supposed to call that function. I got really stuck here because I want to use the changed variable later in my code but it doesn't change, which I understand, since I don't return it but have no idea, how to save it when it's called this way.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
x = 1
def do_something(x):
    x += 1

button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda: do_something(x))
root.mainloop()
```

Firstly, I don't understand, why I have to put there the `x` argument, even though it is defined before the function is created (in my code it says, that it is not defined), and secondly, I don't know how to save the `x` for later use. In my code, the function does more than just this, so I can't simply put it in lambda function. I appreciate any help, if I was unclear, please, let me know, I'll try to explain better. Thank you
Now I realized, that probably just because `x` is not defined in that function, the value does not change globally. But still have no idea why its not defined there...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function for how to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to add module `from functools import partial`.

Add the `IntVar()` to the increase counter.

You don't need to do the `lambda` in the `Button` widget keyword command.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


def do_something(var: int, amount: int) -> int:
   result=var.get()
   result += amount   
   var.set(result)

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Increasing counter")

variable = tk.IntVar()

tk.Button(root,
          width=10,
          text="Increase",
          command=partial(do_something, variable, +1)).grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=10)

tk.Label(root,
         width=5,
         height=2,
         textvariable=variable).grid(column=0, row=1,padx=20, pady=10)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The code can be written in two ways:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
x = 1
def do_something():
    global x
    x+=1
    return print(x)

button = tk.Button(root, command=do_something)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Or

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
x = 1

button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda x: x+=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Both versions raise a syntax error.

Comment: import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
x = 1
def do_something():
    global x
    x+=1
    return print(x)

button = tk.Button(root, command=do_something)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()

Comment: I have changed the code try it again